# How to insert array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to insert an array to another array.

I made some example.
Each column has the code and record.  Record will be array which inlcudes field such as dates and counts.

```
var column = [{code:"", record:0}];
var row = [{date:"", count: 0}];
column.length = 0

row.push({date:"2019-01-02", count:1});     
row.push({date:"2019-01-03", count:1});     
column.push({code:"Home", record:row});

row.length = 0;
row.push({date:"2019-01-04", count:2});     
row.push({date:"2019-01-05", count:2});     
column.push({code:"menu1", record:row});

row.length = 0;
row.push({date:"2019-01-06", count:3});     
row.push({date:"2019-01-07", count:3});     
column.push({code:"menu2", record:row});
```

I expected output as following

```
column[0].code: "Home"
column[0].record[0].date:"2019-01-02", column[0].record[0].count:1
column[0].record[1].date:"2019-01-03", column[0].record[1].count:1
column[1].code: "menu1"
column[1].record[0].date:"2019-01-04", column[1].record[0].count:2
column[1].record[1].date:"2019-01-05", column[1].record[1].count:2
column[2].code: "menu2"
column[2].record[0].date:"2019-01-06", column[2].record[0].count:3
column[2].record[1].date:"2019-01-07", column[2].record[1].count:3
```

Actual results

```
column[0].code: "Home"
column[0].record[0].date:"2019-01-06", column[0].record[0].count:3
column[0].record[1].date:"2019-01-07", column[0].record[1].count:3
column[1].code: "menu1"
column[1].record[0].date:"2019-01-06", column[1].record[0].count:3
column[1].record[1].date:"2019-01-07", column[1].record[1].count:3
column[2].code: "menu2"
column[2].record[0].date:"2019-01-06", column[2].record[0].count:3
column[2].record[1].date:"2019-01-07", column[2].record[1].count:3
```

Existing values of record are being replaced with the value of last pushed record with some reason.
Is there any way to expected result?

Comment: Are you using JavaScript or some other programming language?

Comment: I used javascript and didn't use any other programming language.
You can check code on the link below.
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZ10UY9J7ECR

Comment: Arrays are passed by reference so you keep clearing the array with `row.length = 0;` and then you push the latest into an empty array. You can try `var row = [{date:"", count: 0}];` before each `row.length = 0;` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly.
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZ1BEG5VRJ7E